# Solr fq syntax for logical queries

Tags: solr

I want/need to do some more or less complex logical queries in Sol:r and I'm not quite sure about the correct syntax. I searched the web, but with no real success.

Here's what I want (just an example):

```
fq=FIELD1:[(0 TO 3.9) OR (5 TO 9.9)] AND FIELD2:[(2 TO 4.4) OR (0 TO 1) OR (7 TO *)] AND ...
```

It can go quite long and complex, depending on what the user actually activates.
What the user does is activating ranges of different facets to specifiy his search.
So **IN the facet** there's always a **OR logic**, because he wants to spread the search and **between the facets** there's always a **AND logic**.
That's what I want to achieve, but I don't know how to get the syntax working.

Any ideas from your side would be very helpful. Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this I think:

```
fq=FIELD1:([0 TO 3.9] OR [5 TO 9.9]) AND FIELD2:([2 TO 4.4] OR [0 TO 1] OR [7 TO *]) AND ...
```

just need to exchange [ and (.  ( is a grouping operator; [ is a range operator.